# Почему выдаёт ошибку incomparable types: java.util.Scanner and java.lang.String

Tags: java, input, scanner

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner loh = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Включить режим обмана?");


    if (loh == "Да")
        System.out.print("Ты что меня обмануть решил?");

    else {
        if(loh == "Нет")
           System.out.print("Молодец, вот таких уважаем на районе!");
        else
            System.out.print("Что ты несёшь?");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, как вы себе представляете сравнение объекта класса `Scanner` и строки в `if (loh == "Да")`?

Во-вторых, строки в Java сравнивать через `==` нельзя, т.к. такое сравнение проверяет ссылки, а не сами значения, нужно использовать `equals`.

В-третьих, конкретно в вашем случае лучше использовать `switch`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Включить режим обмана?");

    String myStr = scanner.nextLine();

    switch(myStr) {
        case "Да":
            System.out.print("Ты чо меня обмануть решил?");
            break;
        case "Нет":
            System.out.print("Красава вот таких увожаем на районе!");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.print("Что за белеберду ты несёш?");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Хмм.. странно ваш код не работает какаято ошибка в строке  String myStr = scanner.nextLine();

Comment: @АлёшаАвилов поправил.

Answer (score 0):

Ты ж сам объявил `Scanner loh`, а сравниваешь его со строкой: `loh == "Да"`.
Очевидно, что хотел написать `if (loh.nextLine().equals("Да"))` итд

Comment: Но ему придется вводить значение во всех if-ах? Тогда уж старый проверенный способ:
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String string = input.nextLine();
if(string.equals("Да")) ...
   if(string.equals("Нет")) ...